# code works when written but not when defined

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am new here as well as in the programming world, so this might be a question with a rather easy answer but I just don't get it.
I use Jupyter Notebook.

I want to sum certain scores and when I type the code in normally, it works perfectly:

```
select_df = df.filter(like = 'ABC')
select_df = select_df.loc[(df.REF == '000')]
select_df.sum(axis=1)
```

but when I define the function and try it like this, it doesn't work:

```
def sum_score(a, b):
    select_df = df.filter(like = a)
    select_df = select_df.loc[(df.REF == b)]
    select_df.sum(axis=1)

sum_score('ABC', '000')
```

And when I type it as:

```
print(sum_score('ABC', '000'))
```

It just say's **NONE**

Comment: add a `return` line. Your function is not returning anything now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `return` the df from your function:

```
def sum_score(qu, vc):
    select_df = df.filter(like = qu)
    select_df = select_df.loc[(df.REF == vc)]
    select_df.sum(axis=1)
    return select_df # Return the df
```

Then call the function like this:

```
print(sum_score('ABC', 'V000'))
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
def sum_score(qu, vc):
    select_df = df.filter(like = qu)
    select_df = select_df.loc[(df.REF == vc)]
    return select_df.sum(axis=1)

print(sum_score('ABC', 'V000'))
```

Answer (score -1):

function is not returning u with any result.
You can add return to the last line in your function to get the result and use/print it

```
def sum_score(qu, vc):
    select_df = df.filter(like = qu)
    select_df = select_df.loc[(df.REF == vc)]
    return select_df.sum(axis=1)
```

u can get the result like below:

```
sum_res = sum_score('ABC', 'V000')
print(sum_res)
```

or

```
print(sum_score('ABC', 'V000'))
```